# Why is my CSS overriding the CSS in the Wrapper?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, debugging

I'm trying to figure out why the text in the left navigation panel on the following page is shrinking & underlining when you mouseover in Firefox.

http://fundcentre.newireland.ie/

Everything on the left & top is part of a wrapper that we inject our content into. Our content is everything from "FUND CENTRE" down.

Can someone suggest something I could do to sort this issue out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of styles applied in your newIreland.css files. Which are causing this behaviour.

.ClipboardLink a:link, a:hover, a:visited, a:active {

font-family:Arial,Verdana,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;

font-size:12px !important;

padding-bottom:2px;

text-decoration:underline !important;

// check this line making css important causes it to be underline when you hover over

}

Comment: thanks for this, it seems to be the cause of the problems I'm having. Unfortunately, when I remove the !important instruction from the offending css rules it stops interfering with the wrapper page, but it also breaks the style in our content.. it looks like I'll have to figure out how to get my things working some other way

Answer (score 2):

Stick `.content` in front of all your CSS rules.

So `a:hover { ... }` becomes `.content a:hover {...}`

This will limit any damage to the content `div` which appears to be all yours.

Comment: You can limit yourself to just the rules that have a negative effect but you need to track those down first. I'd suggest firebug but is this faster than just going through and adding `.content`?

Comment: Hi Oli, unfortunately this didn't have any effect. I think it's because of the !important rules that I've specified, as pointed out by sushil below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Text on the menu with mouse hover louses "bold" and gets "underline", this because you have :hover behaviors assigned with does properties...

I've took a sneak-peak to your css, but it's way to dense for my time right now... and to repetitive as well!

Try simplifying your css with common class's and find all your :hover events, taking a closer look to does who work on the same html elements as the one's used for the menu...

> better yet, assign to the menu id or
>   class an :hover event with the same
>   properties than does used for the menu in normal
>   state!!